# how to dynamically add element to a DataTable ipyvuetify?

Tags: python, vuetify.js

I'm creating an interface with the [ipyvuetify](https://github.com/mariobuikhuizen/ipyvuetify) for a python workflow. At some point I need to change items dynamically in a DataTable but I cannot manage to make it change.

I created this small use case to show the bug. LEts assume that we want to create a new class that is inheriting from v.DataTable. this datatable will have 3 based items. in the top slot I'll add a btn, and when the btn is click, one element is added to the items list :

```py
import ipyvuetify as v

class CustomData(v.DataTable):
    
    def __init__(self):
    
        # create a btn to click on  
        
    
        # create the object 
        super().__init__()
        
         # a header 
        self.headers = [
            { 'text': 'Dessert (100g serving)', 'value': 'name'},
            { 'text': 'Calories', 'value': 'calories' },
            { 'text': 'Fat (g)', 'value': 'fat' },
            { 'text': 'Carbs (g)', 'value': 'carbs' },
            { 'text': 'Protein (g)', 'value': 'protein' },
            { 'text': 'Iron (%)', 'value': 'iron' },
        ]
        
        # 3 initial items
        self.items = [
            {
                'name': 'Frozen Yogurt',
                'calories': 159,
                'fat': 6.0,
                'carbs': 24,
                'protein': 4.0,
                'iron': '1%',
            },
            {
                'name': 'Ice cream sandwich',
                'calories': 237,
                'fat': 9.0,
                'carbs': 37,
                'protein': 4.3,
                'iron': '1%',
            },
            {
                'name': 'Eclair',
                'calories': 262,
                'fat': 16.0,
                'carbs': 23,
                'protein': 6.0,
                'iron': '7%',
            }
        ]
        
        # add a slot btn 
        self.btn = v.Btn(children=["click to add item"], color="primary", class_='ma-2')
        self.v_slots = [{
            'name': 'top',
            'children': self.btn
        }]
        
        # js behaviour 
        self.btn.on_event('click', self._on_click)
        
    def _on_click(self, widget, event, data):
        
        new_item = {
            'name': 'Cupcake',
            'calories': 305,
            'fat': 3.7,
            'carbs': 67,
            'protein': 4.3,
            'iron': '8%',
          }
        
        self.items.append(new_item)
        
        return self
toto = CustomData()
toto
```

Now if I click on the btn, the item is added to `toto.items` but this change is not reflected in the display.

If I try to do the same outside of my class :

```py
new_item = {
            'name': 'Cupcake',
            'calories': 305,
            'fat': 3.7,
            'carbs': 67,
            'protein': 4.3,
            'iron': '8%',
          }

toto.items = toto.items + [new_item]
```

the table change and I also see the previously added item.

The question is simple what is triggering the update of the table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Jupyter Widgets, you have to redefine the .items.   If you append to the items list, the widget can't see that the mutable list has been edited.  So below is basically the same solution you suggested outside of your class

```py
class CustomData(v.DataTable):
    
    def __init__(self):
    
        # create a btn to click on  
        
    
        # create the object 
        super().__init__()
        
         # a header 
        self.headers = [
            { 'text': 'Dessert (100g serving)', 'value': 'name'},
            { 'text': 'Calories', 'value': 'calories' },
            { 'text': 'Fat (g)', 'value': 'fat' },
            { 'text': 'Carbs (g)', 'value': 'carbs' },
            { 'text': 'Protein (g)', 'value': 'protein' },
            { 'text': 'Iron (%)', 'value': 'iron' },
        ]
        
        # 3 initial items
        self.items = [
            {
                'name': 'Frozen Yogurt',
                'calories': 159,
                'fat': 6.0,
                'carbs': 24,
                'protein': 4.0,
                'iron': '1%',
            },
            {
                'name': 'Ice cream sandwich',
                'calories': 237,
                'fat': 9.0,
                'carbs': 37,
                'protein': 4.3,
                'iron': '1%',
            },
            {
                'name': 'Eclair',
                'calories': 262,
                'fat': 16.0,
                'carbs': 23,
                'protein': 6.0,
                'iron': '7%',
            }
        ]
        
        # add a slot btn 
        self.btn = v.Btn(children=["click to add item"], color="primary", class_='ma-2')
        self.v_slots = [{
            'name': 'top',
            'children': self.btn
        }]
        
        # js behaviour 
        self.btn.on_event('click', self._on_click)
        
    def _on_click(self, widget, event, data):
        
        new_item = {
            'name': 'Cupcake',
            'calories': 305,
            'fat': 3.7,
            'carbs': 67,
            'protein': 4.3,
            'iron': '8%',
          }
        
#         self.items.append(new_item)
        self.items = self.items + [new_item] 
        
        return self
toto = CustomData()
toto
```